# Adding custom routes to Symfony without using the route loader

Tags: symfony, routes, symfony5

Recently I've hit a wall regarding one feature we need - routing.

The routes in our application are static, but depending on the environment the urls differ.  By default Symfony generates routes based on RouteLoaders and RouteCollections which are then stored in cache, making changing urls based on envs somewhat of a problem.

Is there a way to add routes to the router *after* the boot but **before** it's used so that I can inject my routes with my envs already loaded in from the correct environment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can dynamically configure your routes using the [php route configuration format](https://symfony.com/doc/current/configuration.html#configuration-formats), or you can override the `loadRoutes` method in `Kernel.php`.

**1. Overriding the loadRoutes method**

```
// src/Kernel.php

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Kernel\MicroKernelTrait;
use Symfony\Component\Config\Loader\LoaderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel as BaseKernel;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Route;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\RouteCollection;

class Kernel extends BaseKernel
{

    use MicroKernelTrait {
        loadRoutes as protected loadRoutesKernel;
    }

    public function loadRoutes(LoaderInterface $loader): RouteCollection
    {
        // Loading existing routes
        $collection = $this->loadRoutesKernel($loader);

        // you condition with some param, example form $_ENV or $this->getContainer()->getParameter('some_param')

        $collection->add('dynamic-route', new Route('/docs/test', [
            '_controller' => [
                SomeController::class, 'test'
            ]
        ]));

        return $collection;
    }

}
```

This way you can dynamically adjust your routes depending on certain
environment settings.

---

**2. Route configuration using php format**

Create a routes.php file and describe possible routes scenarios depending on your requirements.

```
// config/routes.php

use App\Controller\SomeController;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Loader\Configurator\RoutingConfigurator;

return function (RoutingConfigurator $routes) {
    // your condition
    $routes->add('catalog_list', '/catalog/list')
        ->controller([SomeController::class, 'someAction'])
    ;
};
```

Comment: This all ends up being statically compiled.  Pretty sure the poster wants something dynamic.  Though I am not sure what `environmentally based` means in this context.

Comment: I think this solution is quite suitable for his task. It just needs to generate routes depending on some value from env

Comment: Maybe you are right.  However changing an env variable is not going to cause your function to kick off.  The cache would have to rebuilt.  Which I think is what the OP is trying to avoid.  Let's see if the OP comes back.

Comment: I believe this gets compiled into cache, which is something I'd like to avoid. @Cerad I meant by using the env variables

Comment: @P.K. Changed my answer, I think dynamic injection of routes in Kernel.php will solve your problem. (see point 1)

Comment: Although this option may not work either if your variables change while the program is running.

Comment: @emrdev Sadly no.  Kernel::configureRoutes is part of the compile phase.  It only gets kicked off when the cache is built.  Kernel::boot gets run on each request.  If you were interested then you might grab the router and try adding routes.  Not sure if it will let you do that or not.  Suspect not.  There are some docs on dynamic routing.  I'm just too lazy to read them.